# Как назвать переменную/className "pop-up" ? Сложно

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, popup

Здравствуйте,

Как правильно назвать переменную pop-up? (именно такое написание правильное в вики)
Вариант:

```
<div class="pop_up">
let popUp;
```

Или

```
<div class="popup">
let popup;
```

Я в замешательстве, по тому что в оригинале дефис.. И это оказалось проблема, по тому что у меня в коде теперь оба написания popup popUp.. не могу сам сообразить или нагуглить как обращаться с дефисом то (изначально pop-up же)

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Какой стиль используется в остальной части проекта вами?
В js как правило все переменные объявляются в camelCase

Comment: Да, используется стиль camelCase, а в css: .camel_case

Comment: Понимаю, по неопытности тоже был бардак в именах, в итоге пришёл к camelCase т.е. popUp. Кстати, pop-up нужно использовать ещё с каким-нибудь словом т.к. pop-up это прилагательное, например popUpWindow или popUpAlert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, этот вопрос лежит больше в области английского языка, чем программирования :-) Если вы хотите придерживаться граммар-наци-правил, то `class="pop-up"`, `let = popUp` будет правильно.